# Learning javascript/jQuery: how to place a number of elements in available window space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, resolution

Using javascript/jQuery:

I have an array with images and I need to display them in my web. The number of images will vary.
Depending on the width and height available due to screen resolution I will display x rows and y columns in order to fill the space.
All images are width=115px and height=120px

When the rows of images go out of view (the vertical scroll shows) **I need to place them in a new div (id='slide')**. This new div I will use to create a slide and show a second/third .. set of images by the clicking of an arrow.

I'm calculating the dimensions of the space available using:

```
function Resize(){
    var docheight = jQuery('.main_insidem').height();    
    var docwidth = jQuery('.main_insidem').width();
    jQuery('.main_insidem').html(docheight+' '+docwidth);
}
```

And everything is contained in

```
<div id="slidesContainer"></div>
```

I need to end up with something like:

```
<div id='slide'><img src='image1.jpg'><img src='image2.jpg'><img src='image3.jpg'><img src='image4.jpg'><img src='image5.jpg'>..</div>

<div id='slide'><img src='imagex+1.jpg'><img src='imagex+2.jpg'><img src='imagex+3.jpg'><img src='imagex+4.jpg'><img src='imagex+5.jpg'>..</div>

<div id='slide'><img src='imagey+1.jpg'><img src='imagey+2.jpg'><img src='imagey+3.jpg'><img src='imagey+4.jpg'><img src='imagey+5.jpg'>..</div>
.
```

.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images load within a container. As you resize window, images will adjust accordingly. No need to do any width or height calculations.

**jQuery**

```
$("img").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400 * index).fadeIn(300);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
img{
    display:none;
    margin:5px 5px 0 0;
    float:left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">   
    <img ...>
    <img ...>
    ..
</div>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/38D6f/1/

Comment: No worries, I'll delete my above comment then. Also, I like the workaround on your `delay()` I hadn't thought of doing that, before :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i would use CSS for this

Float: left; on the images and they will automatically adjust to the width.

overflow: hidden; on the slides container

```
$("#SliderContainer").resize(Resize());
```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: sorry I did not explain myself, I'm rushing please see my intial post again and sorry once more.

Comment: if you want to achieve this you could place your elements in the slider container, set overflow to hidden, and control the scrolling with buttons using jquery: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: I have my imageFlow ready, what I need is to place a set of images in <div id='slide'></div>. The number of images in the set is the number that can be contained in the width and height available depending on screen size. That's where I need the help, sorry for explaining so badly I need it asap and I guess I'm not focusing. Thanks!